# Trigging Interrupt on all Quartz .NET IInterruptableJob

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm working with Quartz scheduler, and attempting to close all jobs on shutdown of the app. I have one specialty job that does a 'Hold' or 'Busy-wait', basically until it gets a condition it sits there waiting patiently.

This job is new, due to a new integration point. The app is run as a service using Topshelf, and whenever we try to shutdown the service to upgrade it, now that this job is running, we have to end up restarting the server to get it to shutdown.

Anyhow, here it gets weird, I have a single jobtype, and when i try to trigger the interrupt in the following section of code using the jobs `FireInstanceId` or `JobKey`:

```
_logger.InfoFormat("{0} scheduler interrupting listener", scheduler.SchedulerName);
scheduler.Interrupt(ListenerKeys.Realtime);

_logger.InfoFormat("{0} scheduler shutting down", scheduler.SchedulerName);
scheduler.Shutdown(true);

_logger.InfoFormat("{0} scheduler shut down", scheduler.SchedulerName);
```

I get an exception:

> Job 'Listeners.Realtime' can not be interrupted, since it does not implement Quartz.IInterruptableJob

One would assume this is straight forward. However Here is the ONLY job that uses this job key:

```
ListenerJob : BaseJob, IInterruptableJob
{
    // some other code referenced in ExecuteJob
    public void Interrupt()
    {
        _dequeuer.StopDequeing();
    }
}
```

I'd go out on a limb and say that's how you implement it, so my question becomes: is there a known bug in Quartz? Is there an issue with group-keys and interrupts maybe? Is there just a way to tell the scheduler to interrupt ALL jobs that are interruptable? Is there an alternative?

UPDATE

I decided to run the following code for more diagnostics from below answers. var interfaces does in fact include IInterruptableJob

```
var jobs = scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs().Where(x => Equals(x.JobDetail.Key, ListenerKeys.Realtime));

var job1 = jobs.First();

var interfaces = job1.JobDetail.JobType.GetInterfaces();
```

Additionally, I ran ReportInterruptableJob as suggested below, which checked the assembly and confirmed ListenerJob implements the interface.

UPDATE2:

Ok, I went out to git hub, and ran the exact meshos. Job.JobInstance as IInterruptableInterface returns null, which is why I get the error. What I don't understand I guess, I how the JobInstance is formed around the IJo which does implement IInterruptableJob

UPDATE3: Ok.... So I found something in the bootstrap that is using JobWrapper<>. I know nothing about it, but Im sure that is part of it.

Comment: I once had a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537460/testing-for-iinterruptablejob

Comment: Can you add some kind of logging mechanism to see if your ListenerJob.Interrupt method is being called?  Can you wrap it in a try catch (and log in the catch) to make sure the code inside the method isn't crapping-out?

Comment: @granadaCoder I know for a fact it is not being hit, as the exception is thrown when trying to call the method. Also, I've left a break-point on there, just to double check my theory and confirmed it was not being hit.

Comment: I appended my answer.........basically, I posted some code so you can fish a little better to make sure the assumed JobKey is actually there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I agree with the other Answer (C Knight) that the JobKey may be off.

If you've implemented the interface...and you have the right JobKey..then you should not get that exception.

Below is the code I have for the interrupting a job.  I'm trying to find the "findthekey" logic as well.

```
 private static void InterruptAJob(JobKey foundJobKey, IScheduler sched)
    {
        if (null != foundJobKey)
        {
            sched.Interrupt(foundJobKey);
        }
    }
```

APPEND

Here is my code for finding a job key.

I would start with it..........put some breakpoints...and see if your JobKey is in the collection.  Maybe modify the routine (after you figure out the magic-places) to find a job key by a certain criteria..and throw an exception if you don't find what you're expecting to find.  Aka, don't "assume" the JobKey exists.....but query for it and throw the appropriate exception (or write the appropriate == null logic if no match is found).......vs the "assume it has to be there" approach.

Again, the below is "starter" code.......my Proof of Concept only had one job in it, so I didn't have to be specific.

```
private static JobKey FindaJobKey(IScheduler sched, ILogger logger)
{
    JobKey returnJobKey = null;

    IList<string> jobGroupNames = sched.GetJobGroupNames();

    if (null != jobGroupNames)
    {
        if (jobGroupNames.Count > 0)
        {
            GroupMatcher<JobKey> groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(jobGroupNames.FirstOrDefault());
            Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> keys = sched.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
            returnJobKey = keys.FirstOrDefault();

            if (null == returnJobKey)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No JobKey Found");
            }
        }

    }

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    return returnJobKey;

}
```

APPEND:

Maybe something like this:

```
private static JobKey FindJobKey(IScheduler sched, ILogger logger, string jobGroupName)
{
    JobKey returnJobKey = null;

    IList<string> jobGroupNames = sched.GetJobGroupNames();

    if (null != jobGroupNames)
    {
        string matchingJobGroupName = jobGroupNames.Where(s => s.Equals(jobGroupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (null != matchingJobGroupName)
        {
            GroupMatcher<JobKey> groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(matchingJobGroupName);
            Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> keys = sched.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);

            if (null != keys)
            {
                if (keys.Count > 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("More than one JobKey Found. (JobGroupName='{0}')", jobGroupName));
                }
                returnJobKey = keys.FirstOrDefault();

                if (null != returnJobKey)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("No JobKey Found. (JobGroupName='{0}')", jobGroupName));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    return returnJobKey;
}
```

Another quick and dirty "look at what you got going on" method.

```
    private static void ShowJobs(IScheduler sched)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : Start");
        GroupMatcher<JobKey> matcherAll = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup();
        Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> jobKeys = sched.GetJobKeys(matcherAll);
        foreach (JobKey jk in jobKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", jk.Group, jk.Name));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : End");
        Console.WriteLine("");

    }
```

APPEND:

Maybe come at it another way.  I slightly adjusted one method.  But added a new one.
ReportIInterruptableJobs

See what ReportIInterruptableJobs reports.

```
    private static void ShowJobs(IScheduler sched, ILogger logger)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : Start");
        GroupMatcher<JobKey> matcherAll = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup();
        Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> jobKeys = sched.GetJobKeys(matcherAll);
        foreach (JobKey jk in jobKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", jk.Group, jk.Name));
            IJobDetail jobData = sched.GetJobDetail(jk);
            if (null != jobData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", jobData.JobType.AssemblyQualifiedName));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : End");
        Console.WriteLine("");

    }

    private static void ReportIInterruptableJobs()
    {
        Type typ = typeof(IInterruptableJob);
        ICollection<Type> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => typ.IsAssignableFrom(p)).ToList();
        if (null != types)
        {
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", t.AssemblyQualifiedName));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I used your methods, and it did return Listeners.Realtime even after I turned off al lother job startups and initializations.

Comment: Right, so using the JobKey you have (Listeners.Realtime), does it point to ListenerJob (class/assembly)? (.using the code snipplets above to glean clues)

Comment: ReportInterruptableJobs confirms my listenerJob implements the interface.

Comment: That makes two of us. So i went out to github and looked at stuff, I should be able to cast job-instance as IInterruptable job, but I cannot.

Comment: I guess make sure you don't have multiple assembles...representing the IInteruptable job.......Aka, you're using one file to build your job..then a different (same name assembly, but just "different")......aka, they look like the same interface, but may not exactly the same because of different assembly.

Comment: Actually, I just made progress. I *sarcasm* love working apps I didnt write. Apparently JobWrapper is being used, there is my problem, now i just need to come to understand jobwrapper. It was hidden away in autofac.

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% positive that the `JobKey` for your `ListenerJob` is in fact `Listeners.Realtime`? Could there be a different job that uses that `JobKey`? Could `Listeners.Realtime` be being updated to a different value by the time you call `Interrupt()`? Quartz is definitely finding a job with that `JobKey`, because Quartz does not throw an exception if it doesn't find a job at all. The job it IS finding does not implement IInterruptableJob. I would double check the `JobKey` value for your `ListenerJob` by setting a breakpoint in the `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` method of `ListenerJob` and inspecting the `context.JobDetail.Key`. My money is on the `JobKey` being different. Also, it might be helpful for us to see what the code for your `BaseJob` is.

Comment: Chris: II followed the suggestion below to determine that it was the right key, and it does appear to be,

Comment: I saw this comment in the source code for Interrupt(): "If more than one instance of the identified job is currently executing, the method will be called on each instance.  However, there is a limitation that in the case that one instance throws an exception, all remaining  instances (that have not yet been interrupted) will not have their method called." I would suggest running scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs().Where(x => Equals(x.JobDetail.Key, ListenerKeys.Realtime)); and see if more than job is returned and if all the jobs returned implement IInterruptableJob

Comment: Excellent method: It returned two instances of ListenerJob (which is correct) jobs, both of which implement IInterruptableInterface.

I am appending more information above