# How to interrupt Topshelf.Quartz job?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, topshelf

I run Topshelf.Quartz scheduler. How can I interrupt running job if I have a stopped topshelf service?

```
s.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
                    q.WithJob(() =>
                        JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build())
                        .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(b => b
                                .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                                .RepeatForever())
                            .Build()));
```

**To clarify, I don't have a sсheduler instance to cause an interruption.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigging Interrupt on all Quartz .NET IInterruptableJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631573/trigging-interrupt-on-all-quartz-net-iinterruptablejob)

Comment: Still no answers?

Comment: I still haven't found solution:(

Answer (score 0):

From [example](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/03340367a8fbce6d3666bd4965060306f7b223d9/src/Quartz.Examples/example7/InterruptExample.cs):

```
IScheduler sched = GetScheduler();

sched.Interrupt(job.Key);
```

Comment: That's cool! But I was asking about Topshelf (see code example).